# Price values are saving as zero in sales_order_item table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

In sales_order_item table price, original_price values are saving as zero, other values are saving correct only.what could be the reason for saving those values as zero.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the "price" and "original_price" values are being saved as zero in the "sales_order_item" table in Magento, there could be a few possible reasons for this:

1. Pricing Rules: If you have any pricing rules set up in your Magento store, it's possible that they are causing the "price" and "original_price" values to be set as zero. Check your pricing rules and make sure they are configured correctly.
2. Custom Code: If you have any custom code in your store that is modifying the pricing of products, it's possible that this code is causing the "price" and "original_price" values to be set as zero.
3. Tax Calculation: If you have tax settings configured in your Magento store and they are not set up correctly, it's possible that this is causing the "price" and "original_price" values to be set as zero.
4. Product Configuration: If the product configuration is not set up correctly, it's possible that this is causing the "price" and "original_price" values to be set as zero.

I would recommend checking each of these areas to try to identify the root cause of the issue.